# send(), returns Winsock Error 10038

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, multithreading, winsock

**Problem:**

- Call to **send()**, returns Winsock Error **10038** against socket handle

**Illustration:**

```
acceptedSocket = accept (server, (sockaddr *)&sin, &len);
```

- **accept()**, returns **0**

  - A new **thread**, is created for each connection
  - **send()**, (in thread function) returns **10038**

**Illustration:** - in thread function

```
//omitted
SOCKET RemoteSocket = (SOCKET) client;
//omitted
send (RemoteSocket, stringToSpend, strlen(stringToSpend), 0)
```

**Suggestions:**

- Possible, race condition?
- Could use I/O completion ports, but not at this stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the problem in the line

```
acceptedSocket = accept (server, (sockaddr *)&sin, &len) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

You make `acceptedSocket` the result of the comparison, but you should store the actual socket returned from accept somehow:

```
acceptedSocket = accept (server, (sockaddr *)&sin, &len);
isOK= acceptedSocket!=INVALID_SOCKET;
```

Although I'm a bit confused by the unbalanced parentheses in your post, so I may be wrong

Answer (score 2):

accept() returns you a handle to a new connection-specific socket. for server code it's 2+ sockets involved: one is in listen state you are calling accept() for and second is one returned from accept() - it's an incoming connection socket. Following accept() can return socket for second incoming connection etc. if accept() returns 0 it's not an incoming connection - it's an error.

Comment: One correction: accept returning 0 is a normal (successful) execution. Errors are signalized by -1

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems like your `send` is executing too fast before the `accept` happened. So the socket used in send is not valid at the point send is executed. One of the obnoxious feature of multithreading. You need to wait for an event at the `send` thread and fire an event when an accept occurs

Comment: A socket handle is defined as "a non-negative integer". So, I believe, zero is valid?